# How do I create a histogram out of this datastructure: x[i] = value_i?

Tags: list-manipulation, histograms

Here is my SSCCE:

```
a[1] = 2; a[2] = 3; a[3] = 6; Histogram[a]
```

This throws and error though. Here are my questions:

1. What kind of data type is a? Is it an Array? a List? So far as I can tell it's neither.
2. How do I get the above to work?

Comment: Do you want an histogram or a bar chart? I suspect you want a bar chart, in which case a={2,3,6}; BarChart[a]

Comment: And to answer your first question, a is a symbol. a={2,3,6} would be a list.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 7):

These are `DownValues`. Lets say you defined a bunch of them as follows.

```
Table[a[i] = 
  RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[100, 1/2]], {i, 10000}]
```

Applying `DownValues` to `a` gives the list you've created.  Here is the first one.

```
DownValues[a] // First

(* HoldPattern[a[1]] :> 46 *)
```

You can similarly get them all at once and use `Histogram` on the values.

```
Histogram[ReleaseHold[First /@ DownValues[a]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. What is the holding bit about?

Comment: `DownValues` uses `HoldPattern` so that it remains unevaluated. `ReleaseHold` does precisely what it says and releases the `HoldPattern` (and other types of held expressions).

Comment: The following is worth reading. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ManipulatingValueLists.html

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work for me:
 a[1] = 1; a[2] = 2; a[3] = 6; a[4] = 2; Histogram[DownValues[a]]
All I get is an empty axis?

Comment: @David which is why Andy used `Histogram[ReleaseHold[First /@ DownValues[a]]]` ... look again.

Comment: Andy, any reason not to use `Histogram[Last /@ DownValues@a]`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard no, not in practice. But I thought using `First` was slightly more instructive for what `DownValues` actually do.

Comment: I think this makes sense to me now. Thanks for your help. One last question: Are there any unintended consequences to using ReleaseHold or DownValues that might cause problems as I use a[] lower in my code?

Comment: @David Is there a motivation for using this unconventional method for manipulating data?

Comment: There shouldn't be any unintended consequences to this approach.